# Word for the bias of a profession towards itself?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am looking for a word or phrase (possibly of the form "*____ bias*") that describes the bias felt by members of a profession towards their own profession, some of examples of which might be:

- An author is more likely to write about characters who are themselves authors, a playwright to write about playwrights, and a painter to paint about the experience of painters.
- An engineer will tend towards trying to solve the problems faced by other engineers.
- A politician is most attuned to the issues faced by people who work in politics.

Example sentence:

> *The engineers don't seem to feel the new project is as important as the old one, but that might just be their _____ bias.*

Comment: It's an aspect of _parochialism_. Every parish has its own traditions.

Comment: @JohnLawler interesting, that does seem to be related. I had been looking over Wikipedia's [List of cognitive biases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cognitive_biases) and not finding anything, but maybe this isn't really a cognitive bias; after all, it doesn't necessarily lead to any inaccurate beliefs, just skewed preferences.

Comment: Perhaps Wikipedia doesn't have all the facts. It's an unavoidable result of being a member of a eusocial species -- we belong to groups and prefer them to other groups. Family, club, cohort, work group, squad, party, you name it, we belong to it. And belonging (and not belonging, like refugees) are very powerful urges (which are biases to some and not to others; depends on who gets to write the coding rules).

Comment: Possibly in-group bias or favoritism or selection bias. Related is the ["if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it's a nail."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)

Comment: An alternative example for authors is something that's a common recommendation: write what you know which I think is what you're reaching for. A person tends to use/solve problems with what they're familiar with.

Comment: See related question and answers: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239900/on-professional-bias

Comment: _The specialist's tendency to see everything in the context/'through the filter' of their own speciality/expertise_.  But that's not so much an answer as a rephrasing of the question...

Comment: One phrase that might work is "occupational exceptionalism." In assessing the merits of nations' behavior, many otherwise level-headed people soberly apply consistent criteria to other countries, but not to their own, giving rise to a sense of "national exceptionalism"—a feeling that the rules of international behavior that ought to and do apply to other countries ought not to and don't apply to their exemplary and exceptional country. I think the occupational version of this phenomenon is common, as people exalt their profession and justify conduct in it that they would condemn outside it.

Comment: @JohnLawler After giving this a few months of thought, I'm convinced that parochialism is the best choice. Alas, it's not an answer! If you'd make it one I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**Collegiate Bias / Collegial Bias**

Although [*colleagiate*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/collegiate) is defined in relation to the word *college*, the word has [generalised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collegiality) to also apply to colleagues or peers in a profession. The alternative word [*collegial*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/collegial) suggested by @TheNate is similar and may be preferred due to its [closer relationship with *colleague*](http://grammarist.com/usage/collegial-collegiate/).

Your question requests a word indicating a bias towards members of someone's own profession. *Professional bias* is a candidate, but the term carries a negative connotation, akin to a [blind spot](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blind%20spot). *Collegiate / collegial bias* refers more strongly to the (positive) peer relationship than to the professional task. The idea is that to a person with a collegiate / collegial bias, peers tend to come to mind before non-peers.

Comment: 'Collegial bias'  sounds more right, spelling notwithstanding, but I like your answer. 

Could go with 'professional", "peer", or even "communal".

Comment: @TheNate Good point. I've added it to my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*The engineers don't seem to feel the new project is as important as the old one, but that might just be their _____ bias.*

In most contexts, the answer would simply be "professional bias", but if the context is about one firm versus another, it could be "company bias" or "corporate bias".

Answer (score 0):

**partisanship**

A partisan is "an adherent or supporter of a person, group, party, or cause, especially a person who shows a biased, emotional allegiance."

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/partisanship?s=t

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like *[chauvinism](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=chauvinism)*

> Prejudiced belief in the superiority of one's own gender, group, or kind: "the chauvinism ... of making extraterrestrial life in our own image" (Henry S.F. Cooper, Jr.)

*American Heritage Dictionary*

Answer (score 0):

I feel like this could be Confirmation Bias ('Myside bias' according to wikipedia, which sounds more in line with your description) with some illusory superiority mixed in.
(https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusory_superiority)