# Term for the narrowing of viewpoint arising from joining a particular profession?

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a term that means something similar to the idea expressed by the phrase “if all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail,” but where the hammer is the set of skills, jargon, norms, etc. associated with a profession.

The term would describe the physicist in [this comic](https://xkcd.com/793/).

There is a Portuguese phrase with this meaning: “deformação profissional” (literally *professional deformation*). It's a play on the phrase “formação profissional” (*professional qualification*).

Comment: My first thought, group think. Or perhaps implicit egotism might fit, the hypothesis that humans have an unconscious preference for things they associate with themselves (hence their career).

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/239900/on-professional-bias

Comment: You might say "He sees things through the lens of his profession"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Professional bias*** is an  expression often  used to refer to the context you describe:

[Déformation professionnelle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C3%A9formation_professionnelle):

> - is a French phrase, meaning a tendency to look at things from the point of view of one's own profession rather than from a broader perspective.
> - ***It is often translated as "professional deformation" or "job conditioning,"***  though French déformation can also be translated as "distortion." The implication is that professional training, and its related socialization, often result in a distortion of the way one views the world.

(Wikipedia)