# How do you call a person who sees his work in everywhere

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

How do you call that person who's so crazy about their work that they see it in everything?

For example, there's a girl who's a grammar teacher. And when she reads a novel, she always explains herself in her head all the grammar rules. Then, there's a tech YouTuber. And every time he sees a new tech coming out, he starts thinking about how would he unbox/review it on his channel.

It's something in psychology.

Can't find the words anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps an [**obsessive**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/obsessive) – A person who is affected by an obsession. *His reputation has always been that of an obsessive, picking at detail in a way which could drive others frantic.*

Comment: The description of the behaviour is [*professional bias*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/388360/term-for-the-narrowing-of-viewpoint-arising-from-joining-a-particular-profession/388378#388378). It's unclear how you want to turn that into a single-word noun for a person. (I don't think it exists.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a well-known saying related to this: **when all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail.** [TFD explains it thus:](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/when+all+you+have+is+a+hammer%2c+everything+looks+like+a+nail)

> One might not recognize other possible outcomes or solutions if one relies too much on a specific tool, method, or mindset. This phrase is typically attributed to 20th-century psychologist Abraham Maslow.